# Power BI Clustered Column Visual Label Offset

Tags: powerbi

I have a clustered column chart showing data for 3 years. I have enabled a calendar drilldown and included a 3 year legend which generates specific column colours for each of the 3 years in every drilldown. this is exactly what I want.
However, adding the 'Year' to the legend causes the top-level view of clustered column chart to expect 3 columns per year and therefore makes the x-axis label appear offset to the left and right columns.
Unfortunately if I remove the legend the drilldown views all lose the 3 year split affect.

I have considered developing a custom overlay for the x-axis but this would not work when I drilldown on the visual.
I don't want to turn the x-axis labels off as this users won't be able to identify what the visual is showing.